# Codename one create radio button using codenameone designer

Tags: java, radio-button, codenameone

How do you get around using codenameone designer to make a functional radio button. I have tried to create in on my form and made properties to be:

```
UIID: RadioButton
Icon: radioEmpty.png
PressedIcon: radioFull.png
Toggle: [checked]
```

it still will not work like a radio button, is there something am missing or what am I doing wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define more than one radio button and set them all to the same group name.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, it helped me see where I was going wrong, thus I thanked you for it